# Finding Matrix adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Need someone to check my reasoning as I don't feel confident in this topic:

consider $P_2$(C) with inner product $$<p(x), q(x)> =  \int {q(x)p(x) dx} $$

T is defied by T(p(x)) = p'(x) + p(x)

Find T*(p(x)) for an arbitrary polynomial of degree 2

1. first thing to do is to find a matrix of T, applying standard basis

   T($x^2$) = 4x

   T(x) = x + 1

   T(1) = 1

   So, $$[T]_\alpha = 
           \begin{matrix}
           0 & 0 & 0 \\
           4 & 1 & 0 \\
           0 & 1 & 1 \\
           \end{matrix}
            $$
2. Find A* of A

   $$A^t  =  
           \begin{matrix}
           0 & 4 & 0 \\
           0 & 1 & 1 \\
           0 & 0 & 1 \\
           \end{matrix}
            $$

   $$A^*  =  
           \begin{matrix}
           0 & 4 & 0 \\
           0 & 1 & 1 \\
           0 & 0 & 1 \\
           \end{matrix}
            $$

But this is obviously not right, as I am given def of inner product, which I did not make any use of.
So, please, point at the mistake

Comment: For the integral, you need to define the upper and lower limits.  (Also you should integrate $p(x) \overline{q(x)}$ since you are working over the complex numbers.)

Comment: Anyway, the trick is to find an orthonormal basis of your vector space.  You can do this using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization on the standard basis.  Then find your matrix with respect to THIS basis.  Then the standard transpose works.  Then to figure out $T^*(p)$, you first need to write p in terms of the basis, and then apply $A^*$ to that, then write out the polynomial that represents.

Comment: Thank you! So, I just  should do all the same steps, but with orthonormal basis instead of the standard one?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Given a square matrix representing a linear operator, the adjoint matrix is defined to be the conjugate transpose matrix ***only if your original matrix is with respect to an orthonormal basis.*** Try the question again with this information and you will realize that your given inner product will come into play.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the definition of the adjoint, as we will do below.
First, let the basis $\alpha = (1,x,x^2)$.
Then
$$
T(a+bx+cx^2) = (a+bx+cx^2) + (a+bx+cx^2)' = (a+b) + (b+2c)x + cx^2,
$$
and we can represent the linear operator $T$ in coordinates given by basis $\alpha$ as
\begin{align}
T_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\ 0&1&2\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
The adjoint $T^*$ behaves as
\begin{align}
\langle T(p(x)), q(x) \rangle = \langle p(x), T^*(q(x)) \rangle
\end{align}
so we can find $T^*_\alpha$ from
\begin{align}
\langle T_\alpha(a,b,c), (a',b',c') \rangle &= \langle(a+b,b+2c,c),(a',b',c')\rangle\\
&=\langle (a,b,c), (a',a'+b',2b'+c')\rangle\\
&=\langle (a,b,c), T^*_\alpha (a',b',c') \rangle\rangle\\
\end{align}
and conclude that $T^*_\alpha (a',b',c') = (a',a'+b',2b'+c')$ which can be expressed as
\begin{align}
T^*_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&2&1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus $T^*_\alpha$ is not the conjugate transpose of $T_\alpha$; this only works when $\alpha$ is an orthonormal basis.